# How to update the value of an object in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm sort of new to programming with CoreData, so I have no idea how to go about doing this. I'm trying to update a string that's being stored in a CoreData object, but I have not the faintest idea on how to do that. Here's my code:

Here's where I make the new object:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
     self.steakName = @"No Name";
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
     NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

     [newManagedObject setValue:self.steakName forKey:@"steakName"];

     // Save the context.
     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![context save:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         abort();
     }
}
```

Here's where I want to update it: (It's being updated in a different class then where it's being made.)

```
- (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    masterViewController.steakName = [self.steakNameTextField text];
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = masterViewController.steakName;
    NSLog(masterViewController.steakName);
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, your code looks like it would work so we do not know what problem you are having.

Comment: I'm not having a problem, I'm just trying to figure out how to do something, so I'm giving you the code that I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it **almost** the same way you would without Core Data.  Keep a reference to the object as a property in the class where it's created and make whatever changes you want.  The only difference is, when you want the changes to persist, you save your context again.

Comment: But there's going to be more than one object in the table, so how would that work?

Comment: I'm also trying to change the object in a different class than what it was created in, so how would I save the context?

Comment: If you're trying to save it in a different class, then you have to pass your context along to that class. In fact, if you're passing the object along, you can ask the object for its context instead of passing the context over. self.myObject.managedObjectContext...

Comment: Whether you're using Core Data or not you need some way of identifying which object you're going to modify, which means you have to get a reference to it.  Either you keep the reference when you create it or you create a fetch request to get the object(s) out of storage and into memory, which gets you a reference (or an array of them).